# How to use one Series with multiple ChartAreas?

Tags: c#, charts, series

I have a `Chart` with three `ChartArea`s. The first chart area, `chartarea1` plots data from `series1`, `chartarea2` plots `series2`. But then I'd like `chartarea3` to plot `series1` and `series2`. All my searches return ways of plotting multiple `Series` on a `ChartArea` and I don't have  a problem with that, what I want to do is plot a `Series` on multiple `ChartArea`s. Is there a way to do this? The `Series["item"].ChartArea` property only sets one `ChartArea`.

This is my attempt, I tried creating `series3` and `series4` and assigned them `series1` and `series2` respectively, but it's not working (I suspect because they are reference-types and it doesn't actually clone `series1` and `series2` which I feel like I am going to have to do).

```
ChartArea chartarea1 = new ChartArea();
chartarea1.Name = "chartarea1";
chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartarea1);

Series series1 = new Series();
series1.Name = "series1";
series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
chart1.Series.Add(series1);
chart1.Series["series1"].ChartArea = "chartarea1";

chart1.Series["series1"].Points.DataBindY(someArray1);

ChartArea chartarea2 = new ChartArea();
chartarea2.Name = "chartarea2";
chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartarea2);

Series series2 = new Series();
series2.Name = "series2";
series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
chart1.Series.Add(series2);
chart1.Series["series2"].ChartArea = "chartarea2";

chart1.Series["series2"].Points.DataBindY(someArray2);

ChartArea chartarea3 = new ChartArea();
chartarea3.Name = "chartarea3";
chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartarea3);

Series series3 = series1;
Series series4 = series2;
series3.Name = "series3";
series4.Name = "series4";
chart1.Series["series3"].ChartArea = "chartarea3";
chart1.Series["series4"].ChartArea = "chartarea3";

chart1.Invalidate();
```

As of now, when I exclude the code involving `chartarea3`, `series3` and `series4`, it plots as I would expect: two line graphs, first showing the data from `someArray1` and the second below, which shows the data from `someArray2`. But if I include the the rest of the code, then the form shows a large blank space where `chartarea1` and `chartarea2` are supposed to be, then `chartarea3` below with `sommeArray1` and `sommeArray2` plotted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. Each Series can only reside in one ChartArea. You can easily clone the two Series and display them in the 3rd ChartArea.

Comment: How would I got about that? Would that involve writing a method to clone the properties of the `Series` I specify?

Comment: Yes. If you do involved styling you may want to write one or two  styling method(s) you apply to both sets of series to avoid code redundancy. Note that the DataPoints must be added in a loop as there is neither a AddRange nor even a constructor for the Points collection..: `foreach (DataPoint dp in s1.Points) s2.Points.Add(dp.Clone());`

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. Thanks @TaW